# Is my idea for a robust easily resizeable button with a background good?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I started creating a site using `<span>` that was set to `inline-block` and setting the background. Then I would put some text inside it (the button text). This worked well because I was using sprites for performance. Then I realised I need to resize the button. I cant resize the sprite because it throws out all my locations. I have now decided that for all buttons that need to resize I should use individual images.

I have two options carry on using an `inline-block` `<span>` with a background or use an image inside a div whose positioning is set to absolute so I can pull text in over it. I think this might be better because then I can size the div rather than the image and everything inside should be easier to make sure it sits in the middle. (like `text-align:center`) for example.

Here is my fiddle, what do you think will this be a safe way of doing it?

http://jsfiddle.net/peter_heard01/CVzHg/

EDIT:

I meant to say the fear I have about the background approach is that I don't believe backgrounds resize very well on older browsers?

Comment: See the comment in my answer about the browser support. Or read [here](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely div with a background-position set to center center and background size to 100% 100% (note that it won't keep the aspect ratio). Keep the button title absolutely positioned, top 50% and a negative top margin (see what works the best, it should be negative 50-75% of the font size). Background-position also allows for easier image swapping on mouse over, etc. rather than having to write Javascript to change the image source on mouseover and mouseout events.

But again, you should do it the way it works the best *for you*.

See my example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CVzHg/3/).

```
div.button{
background: url('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png') center center;
text-align: center;
background-size: 100% 100%;
width:400px;
height:120px;
position: relative;
}

div.title{
width:100%;
height:100%;
top:50%;
font-size: 16px;
margin-top: -12px;
position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: but background resizing doesn't work on older browsers does it?

Comment: im also not concerned about aspect ratio I will do the math before hand, as you have to use and width AND height for firefox anyway....

Comment: What browsers are you targetting? Everything since IE9, FF4, Opera 10 and webkit since long ago support background size.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your goal is, you may consider to use a 9-tile background image. You probably know the technique: You have 9 images for each corner of the button, ceiling, bottom, left, right, and center. In your website you create a 3x3 table (or DIV-construction) and use the appropriate image as background for each cell (incl. appropriate `background-repeat`).

The advantage of this technique is that the images wont be resized at all. They look perfect in every size.

Loading 9 files is an issue of performance. Therefore, you may also put all images together in one and show the appropriate region using `background-position`. As you rely on the element's clipping in this case and cannot use `background-repeat`, you need a rather large image (as large as the larges button on your site).

Comment: hmm not convinced by this for what I want to do the button has texture all over it in this case, it would be good for a button with just a really nice edge that the browser cant do I guess?

Comment: Exactly. As I wrote: It depends on what you actually need :)

Comment: +1 This is also a great approach when you need something like that. A little bit of a pain is doing the whole 9 parts for mouse over, mouse down, etc.